# Cannot connect to Apache on Google Compute Engine

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have set up a Google Compute Engine and installed Apache on the server.
(The server is running Windows 2008 Server and Apache is running as a service.)
I can connect the server using Remote Desktop. However, I am not able to connect to the webserver. (I have also installed a FileZilla FTP server, but annot connect to ftp either.)
I have opened access to ports 80 and 443 on the Windows firewall, and I have also opened access to the same ports on the VPC Network Firewall:

default-allow-http
Ingress
http-server
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:80
Allow
1000

default-allow-https
Ingress
https-server
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:443
Allow
1000

Still, I am not able to connect to the webserver. I cannot connect to the webserver when I am logged on using Remote Desktop and then trying to connect to 127.0.0.1, either.

I have a similar setup on a virtual server on Rackspace. There everything works as expected. Any tips on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked out the internal firewall-rules from the VM win2008 ? Try to turn off the Firewall from the VM win2008 and test it again. About the filezilla, I am setup my filezilla running by the port 21, so I had opened port 21 from the VPC on my project to allow the access.

Comment: Its not entirely clear from this post, but those firewall rules appear to require the server to have the http-server and https-server labels (as opposed to "apply to all").  Did you label your instance correctly?